# Calling a specific function defined in `argv` for `[<EntryPoint>]` or dynamically naming the function to be called

Tags: f#, entry-point

Is it possible to somehow define the *function* name called and/or *module name* opened dynamically in F#?

Googling the interwebs seems to suggest using introspection is only possible if the "names" are members of a type.

The reason I'm asking is because my solution for [Advent of Code](https://adventofcode.com)'s `[<EntryPoint>]` is starting to look pretty boilerplatey and definitely not DRY.

All my "puzzle solving" functions are defined in Day -specific modules and have the same signature `String -> Unit -> int64` i.e. they take a file name for input (for testing's sake as most, if not all, puzzles have test vectors) and unit (so that they don't all get executed when pattern matching)

```
open AoC2020.Utils
open AoC2020.Day1
open AoC2020.Day2
open AoC2020.Day3
open AoC2020.Day4
open AoC2020.Day5
open AoC2020.Day6
open AoC2020.Day7
open AoC2020.Day8
open AoC2020.Day9

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let day = argv |> getProblem
    match day with
    | "1" -> day1 "1" ()
    | "1b" -> day1part2 "1" ()
    | "2" -> day2 "2" ()
    | "2b" -> day2part2 "2" ()
    | "3" -> day3 "3" ()
    | "3b" -> day3part2 "3" ()
    | "4" -> day4 "4" ()
    | "4b" -> day4part2 "4" ()
    | "5" -> day5 "5" ()
    | "5b" -> day5part2 "5" ()
    | "6" -> day6 "6" ()
    | "6b" -> day6part2 "6" ()
    | "7" -> day7 "7" ()
    | "7b" -> day7part2 "7" ()
    | "8" -> day8 "8" ()
    | "8b" -> day8part2 "8" ()
    | _ -> 1L
    |> printfn "%d"
    0
```

..or am I doing something completely wrong and there's a better way to achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More generally, I would probably not bother creating a sophisticated launcher for Advent of Code - for the few puzzles I did, I just kept the code for each puzzle in a script file and run it by selecting it all and running it in F# Interactive - rather than having a command line interface.

However, if you prefer a command line interface, then you should be able to do what you want using reflection. Each F# module is compiled to a class and you can use `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()` to get a list of all loaded classes, find the class you want and invoke a method that you know it has such as `run`.

For example:

```
module Day1 = 
  let run () = printfn "day 1"

module Day2 = 
  let run () = printfn "day 2"

module Day2b = 
  let run () = printfn "day 2b"
```

A (very basic) function that takes a module name and runs its `run` function looks like this:

```
open System.Reflection

let run name = 
  let typ = 
    Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
    |> Seq.find (fun t -> t.Name = name)
  typ.GetMethod("run").Invoke(null, [||]) |> ignore
```

To test this:

```
run "Day1"
run "Day2"
run "Day2b"
```

Comment: While I agree that _generally_ I wouldn't bother creating a sophisticated launcher - I am using Advent of Code just as a platform to learn doing things _right_ with F# and .NET ... So to me the question of "a sophisticated launcher" is a general one and pretty analogous to e.g. Django's management commands. 
Thanks, I'm pretty sure I kind of understand what's happening here, even with absolutely 0 background with C# :)

Comment: @Kimvais That makes a complete sense! (I just thought I'd add a disclaimer, because some people coming to F# tend to do things in overly complicated ways :-)) Reflection is definitely one of the more mysterious areas of .NET...